# Shared OleDbConnection to FoxPro Database

Tags: c#, datatable, visual-foxpro, foxpro, oledbconnection

I'm trying to read a FoxPro Table into a c# DataTable, problem is I need it to be open somewhere else while I'm reading from it. I've been looking for a way to make the connection shared or something like that. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the method I'm using right now:

```
public DataTable ReadBulkDBC(string dbfFile, string query, int maxRows, string dynamicValue)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1; Mode=Share Deny None; Exclusive=OFF; Data Source=" + dbfFile))
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = query;

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("updateId", typeof(int)));
        if (!dbfFile.Contains("con_compania")) { dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("dynamic", typeof(string))); }
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("fechasync", typeof(DateTime)));

        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        oda.Fill(dt);
        //dt = ds.Tables[0];
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had success in the past by calling SET EXCLUSIVE OFF on the OleDbCommand/Connection prior to using it for the dataset operation.

I've used code like the following as part of "initializing" the connection:

`string commandText = "SET NULL ON\r\nSET DELETED ON\r\nSET EXCLUSIVE OFF";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = commandText;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

This code is executed prior to doing anything else with the connection.

Comment: The other applications should also be opening the FoxPro table in a shared manner, like using SET EXCLUSIVE OFF prior to opening the table or adding the SHARED keyword on the USE command.

Comment: I tried this, problem is I when it hits `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` it asks for an open connection, and that's what I can't do.

Comment: @DidierFuentes do you have an exception stack trace or similar error message details you can share?

Comment: The exception I'm getting when trying to access the file while it's being used is very simple:

`A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot open file c:\...\file.dbc.`

Comment: I see, its a database container that you're unable to open.  The legacy applications I've dealt with have mostly used free tables in a folder without having them associated with a DBC container.  Maybe you can work around the DBC by opening the tables directly from whatever folder they reside in.

Comment: I noted just now that if you open a table associated with a DBC from within FoxPro, it will automatically and silently open the DBC container associated with that file.  If your FoxPro setting is such that the DBC opens exclusively, then another application will not be able to open the file.  Make sure that your FoxPro settings are set to open the DBC container in a shared fashion along with the tables contained within.

Answer (score 0):

By not seeing the values in your variables, you have a parameter of "dbfFile".  Which if this is the name of your actual TABLE, then that is the problem.  Your CONNECTION STRING Should only point to the PATH where your .dbf files are located.  Once the connection to the PATH is connected, you should be able to query from any .DBF within that folder.

Is that what your problem actually is?

Then a question for you... is the SOURCE Application (the VFP version) actually have the file in exclusive mode and not shared?  If that has exclusive, you can't do anything else.

However, if your connection is to the PATH\TableName.dbf, the connection will never open as you can't connect to a .DBF...

If you have access to VFP, and can just for sanity check purposes... Create a new table and add a simple record to it.  Put it in the same path as where your other table you are trying to connect to is located.  Then try to query from THAT NEW table.  The running application has no idea of this table and would therefore never even have it opened.  This way you should have no problem trying to open / query it.

From within VFP...

```
CD "path to your production data"
create table _TempFileForCSharp ( testfield c(10), intfield i )
use
```

Now, from C#, try and run a query against the table "_TempFileForCSharp", just make sure the connection is to the PATH where the .dbf is located, don't connect to the actual .DBF

Comment: No, it isn't, the problem is the database/table is open somewhere else and it can't access it because I can't set the shared connection.

Comment: @DidierFuentes, see revision for feedback

Comment: I changed the connection string to point to the path, same result. The other problem, right now the other application that has the file open is VFP in my computer, using `USE shared`. If I close the file in VFP my application works, but it should be able to open it even if VFP is using it. I am able to access the file if I try to open it directly instead of opening it as a database even when VFP has it open, so I think the problem is with the connection in the application.